# Importing only certain rows after looking at other answered questions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","SHEET1!A5:P85"),"SELECT * WHERE K:K contains 'Name.s'")
```

> Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "K "" at line 1, column 16. Was
>   expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

Trying to get a row of data to appear on another sheet and keep getting this error. Followed a couple of different questions and still can't get it right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- instead of **`K:K`** you need **`Col11`**

  ```
  =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL", "SHEET1!A5:P85"), "where Col11 contains 'Name.s'")
  ```